# Progress Bar with 5% steps

Tags: python, if-statement, progress

I have the following simple code:

```
import sys
num_tasks = 1000000
for i in range(num_tasks):
    if ((i/(num_tasks-1)) % 5):
        sys.stderr.write('\rdone {0:.0%}'.format(i/(num_tasks-1)))
```

My problem is that i just want to show the 5% steps like:

```
done 5%, done 10%, done 15%,...
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's the error/unexpected result? Please add this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`if ((i/(num_tasks-1)) % 5):`

Will be interpreted as `True` in every iteration in which `(i/(num_tasks-1))` is **not** divisible by 5, since `(i/(num_tasks-1)) % 5` will be equal to values different than 0. You should instead do:

`if ((i/(num_tasks-1)) % 5 == 0):`

Comment: Did you try that solution? Because this would just show me `done 0%` as this is just `true` for the very first i-value.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on this line:

`if ((i/(num_tasks-1)) % 5):`

Because `((i/(num_tasks-1)) % 5)` is not a boolean value, your `if` statement will not behave properly. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html) is some more information about the truth values of different primitive types in Python. Try this instead:

`if i/(num_tasks-1) % 5 == 0:`